# Retrieving value from a module.exports array of objects, using wildcard like 'includes'

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, alexa-skills-kit, aws-sdk-nodejs

Hi I have a module exports as such.

```
module.exports = {
"Computer screen": 'phrase1',
"Table height": 'phrase2',
"Temperature": 'phrase3',
};
```

And importing the file that has this using 'require' into a var called tries. Then I use the following code to search the module.exports. For example if searchQuery was "computer screen" then it would return 'phrase1'.

```
var tryThis = tries[searchQuery];
```

My question is how can i modify this so it searches for any line that contains the search query. For example searching 'table' would return 'phrase2'.

Please help :) thanks ahead.

Comment: The JS `includes()` method can query a string for a specified substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're exporting is an object with properties. You can loop through an object's property names using a `for-in` loop (which includes all enumerable properties on the object, both own properties and inherited ones) or by using the array from `Object.keys` (which only includes own enumerable properties). So then you can use `includes` on each property name.

For your specific example, you might use `Object.entries` instead (quite recent, but easily polyfilled), since you may want the value; it returns an array of `[key, value]` arrays.

You seem to be using ES5 level syntax only, so:

```
var tryThis;
Object.entries(tries).some(function(entry) {
    if (entry[0].includes(searchQuery)) {
        tryThis = entry[1];
        return true;
    }
});
```

...or perhaps `entry[0].toLowerCase().includes(searchQueryLower)` (where you have `searchQueryLower = searchQuery.toLowerCase()`) if you want a case-insensitive match.

Live example:

```js
var tries = {
"Computer screen": 'phrase1',
"Table height": 'phrase2',
"Temperature": 'phrase3',
};
var searchQuery = "Table";
var searchQueryLower = searchQuery.toLowerCase();

var tryThis;
Object.entries(tries).some(function(entry) {
    if (entry[0].toLowerCase().includes(searchQueryLower)) {
        tryThis = entry[1];
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(tryThis);
```

In ES2015+ I'd use `for-of` and destructuring:

```
let tryThis;
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(tries)) {
    if (key.toLowerCase().includes(searchQueryLower)) {
        tryThis = value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Live example:

```js
const tries = {
  "Computer screen": 'phrase1',
  "Table height": 'phrase2',
  "Temperature": 'phrase3',
};
const searchQuery = "Table";
const searchQueryLower = searchQuery.toLowerCase();

let tryThis;
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(tries)) {
    if (key.toLowerCase().includes(searchQueryLower)) {
        tryThis = value;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(tryThis);
```

You can, of course, shoehorn that into a `reduce` call (because any array operation can be shoehorned into a `reduce` call), but it doesn't buy you anything (and you can't stop when you find what you're looking for). Similarly it could be done with `map` and `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const search = (exports, word) => (Object.entries(exports).find(([name, value]) => name.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase())) || [])[1]


const module = {}
module.exports = {
  "Computer screen": 'phrase1',
  "Table height": 'phrase2',
  "Temperature": 'phrase3'
};

console.log(search(module.exports, "table"))
console.log(search(module.exports, "fffff"))
```